# Why does the compiler not look in the enclosing class for a method?

Tags: scala, methods, compiler-errors

Have a look at the following Scala example:

```
class A {
  def foo(x: Int): Int = x

  private class B {
    def foo(): Int = foo(3)
  }
}
```

The compiler produces an error message when trying to compile this:

```
A.scala:5: error: too many arguments for method foo: ()Int
                def foo(): Int = foo(3)
                                    ^
```

For some reason the compiler doesn't look in the enclosing class `A` to find the method to call. It only looks in class `B`, finds the `foo` method there that takes no parameters that doesn't fit and then gives up. If I rename the methods, then it works without a problem:

```
class A {
  def bar(x: Int): Int = x

  private class B {
    def foo(): Int = bar(3)
  }
}
```

In this case, the compiler does look in class `A` and finds the `bar` method there.

Why does the first example not work; is this according to Scala's specifications, or is this a compiler bug? If this is according to the rules, then why are the rules like this?

By the way, another way to get around the problem is by using a self type annotation:

```
class A {
  self =>

  def foo(x: Int): Int = x

  private class B {
    def foo(): Int = self.foo(3)
  }
}
```

Comment: Will something like this work for you?

class A {
  def foo(x: Int): Int = x

  private class B extends A {
    @Override def foo(): Int = foo(3)
  }
}

Comment: @Rustem thanks, but I'm more interested in why the rules are this way than a particular solution (I already have a good solution by using the self type annotation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically the class B is a block. You could reduce the problem to the following:

```
def foo(x: Int): Int = x;
{    
   def foo(): Int = foo(3)
}
```

That would cause the exact same problem. It is compliant to the specs, because all names introduced in a block shadow anything that has the same name (ignoring the signature, see chapter 2 of the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)). Overloading is only possible on class level. (chapter 6.26.3 in the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf))